# Appending to file fails in Azure storage account

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I am attempting to write log files for operations in an Azure Databrick.  The log files are written to a file in a Azure storage account.  I am using Python to do this.  As a test, I set up 2 write operations.  The first one writes to a microsecond-timestamped log file, the name essentially being guaranteed to be unique.  The second attempts to write to one called "log", in the same directory, and should simply append the new log lines to the ones already in the file.  Here's the very simple code:

```
log_file = log_dir + '/' + 'log_' + str(log_ts)
with open(log_file, 'a') as l:
  l.write('\n'.join(log_lines_list))
  
log_file = log_dir + '/' + 'log'
with open(log_file, 'a') as l:
  l.write('\n'.join(log_lines_list))
```

There's not really much I see that can go wrong there.  The first file is created and written properly.  The second is unaltered, even the timestamp remaining unaltered; that is, the first run (file creation) of the code works, but subsequent runs (file appends) fail with the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2639275445480394> in <module>
     45 log_file = log_dir + '/' + 'log'
     46 with open(log_file, 'a') as l:
---> 47   l.write('\n'.join(log_lines_list))

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

My research has basically concluded that append operations are not valid in this type of storage.  Is that right?  That seems odd to me, but I am rather new to this.  I suppose I could read the file into a list, append the new lines to the list, rename the file, and write the joined list to a file of the previous name, and delete the renamed file once write is confirmed, but that really seems excessive.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: May I know what kind of blob you created the first time? Block blob or append blob?

Comment: It appears to be block blob.  When I go to the container properties and select "Calculate size", the block blob value is high while page and append blob sizes are exactly 0B.  Perhaps there's a more direct way to find this out; I'm still feeling my way through this.  Is it too simple to say that this means that append operations are not enabled for this blob?

Comment: Yep, maybe you can try append blob.

Comment: Thank you @StanleyGong, I'll do that.